# SkipListener for chain processors and multiple model items

Tags: spring-batch

I want a [SkipListener](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/SkipListener.html) for my [CompositeItemProcessor](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/support/CompositeItemProcessor.html) which is a list of 2 processors processing an item like this:

Reader(itemRead) -> ValidationProcessor(itemRead, item) -> WrapProcessor(item, item)

The problem is that SkipListener accepts only a model item(the `itemRead`, hopefully I'm wrong here) in the 
`onSkipInProcess` like 
`onSkipInProcess(ValidationItem itemRead, Throwable arg1)`
while I want the item from the 2nd processor too, inside this function.

There is also a high chance that the WrapProcessor might change output(depending the requirements) to something like that: `WrapProcessor<item, anotherItem>`

Is there a way to solve this issue?

My compositeItemProcessor config:

```
<bean id="compositeItemProcessor"
                class="org.springframework.batch.item.support.CompositeItemProcessor">
                <property name="delegates">
                        <list>
                                <bean class="com.mycompany.ValidationProcessor">/
                                <bean class="com.mycompany.WrapProcessor" />
                        </list>
                </property>
        </bean>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have your transformed object into a custom skip exception

```
class WrapProcessor implements ItemProcessor<ValidationItem, WrappedObject> {
  O transform(ValidationItem item) {
    WrappedObject wrapped = new Wrapped(item);
    if(some condition) {
      throw new SkipWrappedObject(wrapped);
    }
    ...
  }
}
```

and in `onSkipInProcess(ValidationItem itemRead, Throwable arg1)` arg1 can be casted to `SkipWrappedObject` ad you can access skipped wrapped object